# Unable to detect bug

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have done a react-redux project cloning twitch.A simple streaming app.But the problem is that when I try to delete a stream.My redux-devtool shows that the stream is deleted from the state object.I have also checked my db.json file.The stream was deleted from there too.But After deleting when I return to homepage and fetch the list of streams.The stream again appears.The db.json file doesn't have the stream but the state in redux-devtool show that the stream is in the state.

```js
//Here are my actionCreators
export const createStream = (formValues) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  const { userId } = getState().auth;
  const response = await streams.post("/streams", { ...formValues, userId });
  dispatch({ type: CREATE_STREAM, payload: response.data });
  history.push("/");
};
export const fetchStreams = () => async (dispatch) => {
  const response = await streams.get("/streams");
  dispatch({ type: FETCH_STREAMS, payload: response.data });
};
export const fetchStream = (id) => async (dispatch) => {
  const response = await streams.get(`/streams/${id}`);

  dispatch({ type: FETCH_STREAM, payload: response.data });
};

export const editStream = (id, formValues) => async (dispatch) => {
  const response = await streams.patch(`/streams/${id}`, formValues);
  dispatch({ type: EDIT_STREAM, payload: response.data });
  history.push("/");
};
export const deleteStream = (id) => async (dispatch) => {
  streams.delete(`/streams/${id}`);
  dispatch({ type: DELETE_STREAM, payload: id });
  history.push("/");
};
//here Are the reducers
const streamsReducer = (state = {}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case CREATE_STREAM:
      return { ...state, [action.payload.id]: action.payload };
    case FETCH_STREAM:
      return { ...state, [action.payload.id]: action.payload };
    case EDIT_STREAM:
      return { ...state, [action.payload.id]: action.payload };
    case DELETE_STREAM:
      return _.omit(state, action.payload);
    case FETCH_STREAMS:
      return { ...state, ..._.mapKeys(action.payload, "id") };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
export default streamsReducer;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Does the problem still occur if you hard refresh or start the app again? Because, for me it seems like your browser cached db.json file

Comment: I stooped the app.And did an npm start its working now

Comment: could you clarify why the bug occured

Answer (score 0):

This is not a bug actually. It is just that the browser is caching your db.json file. This means that, there are two versions of db.json. One that you are performing delete operation and one that is cached in your browser. After first fetch from db.json, the next requests are targeting cached db.json. The way to solve it would be to disable caching, but this is not a solution that should be in a real application. In a real app, you would need to use some Database like MySQL, MongoDB where you could store your data.

Comment: Well after a few attempts,i saw that the stream is actually deleted.But when I return to homepage after deleting the the state is not yet updated.But after i reload the browser the stream is deleted.Why is that so?I have an edit stream option too.When i edit it and go back to homepage i fetch the updated state.So why can iget edited state but not deleted?